# ubuntu python 3.4 no site-packages library

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, module, blender

I've been trying to import the blender python library into python so I can use it in another python IDE. I followed some steps on the blender wiki page and achieved the correct files. My only problem left is to copy and past the correct files in the 'site-packages' folder under python 3.4 but I don't have such directory... I did not install this python version manually, It came with Ubuntu by default.

-Bert

The blender wiki page:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

Comment: ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Nothing for python 3.4

Comment: And what's the answer when you run that code under with python3?

Comment: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/dist-python']

Comment: You should follow Daniel Roseman's answer and just let `make install` do the work for you.  But if you want to copy the files manually, use one of the directories you just posted.

Comment: The CMake installer wasn't checking for `dist-packages`, fixed: https://developer.blender.org/rB4560570f8ac91b7ce349c8c1079caaf1f21848bf And if you want to install elsewhere, set `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those instructions are quite clear about what to do: run `make install`. Copying the packages manually is only if you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Good answer, but I think his question is more focused on the instruction "Or if you like to do it manually."